# Intel prefixes instructions, checking optimisations problems

Tags: optimization, x86, intel, disassembly, micro-optimization

I wanted to learn more on ptrace's functions with x86_64 binaries, disassembling instructions.
The goal is to check if a byte is one of instructions prefixes.

I found some information in the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf) (volume 2, chapter 2).

The section `2.1.1 INSTRUCTION PREFIXES` shows the following prefixes:

- [`0x26`] ES segment override
- [`0x36`] SS segment override prefix
- [`0x2E`] CS segment override prefix *or* Branch not taken
- [`0x3E`] DS segment override prefix *or* Branch taken
- [`0x64`] FS segment override prefix
- [`0x65`] GS segment override prefix
- [`0x66`] Operand-size override prefix
- [`0x67`] Address-size override prefix
- [`0xF0`] LOCK prefix
- [`0xF2`] REPNE/REPNZ prefix *or* BND prefix
- [`0xF3`] REP or REPE/REPZ prefix

Visually, [this chart](https://pnx.tf/files/x86_opcode_structure_and_instruction_overview.png) shows prefixes in yellow.

If I want to know if a byte is a prefix, I will try to be efficient and check if it is possible to perform binaries operations.

If I take `0x26`, `0x36`, `0x2E` and `0x3E` as a group. These numbers in base 2 (`00100110`, `00110110`, `00101110` and `00111110`) show a common part: `001XX110`.

An and-binary operation of `11100111` (`0xE7`) can found if my byte is in this group.

Great. Now, if I take a second group which contains `0x64`, `0x65`, `0x66` and `0x67` (`01100100`, `01100101`, `01100110`, `01100111`), I found an other common part: `011001XX`.

Then, the and-binary operation of `11111100` (`0xFC`) can found if the byte is in the second group.

The problem comes for remaining instruction prefixes (`0xF0`, `0xF2` and `0xF3`): There is no common part. An and-operation of `11111100` (`0xFC`) would let the byte `0xF1`.

One solution would be to check after if the byte isn't `0xF1`.

So, a possible implementation in C would be:

```
if ((byte & 0xE7) == 0x26) {
    /* This `byte` is a ES, SS, CS or DS segment override prefix */
}
if ((byte & 0xFC) == 0x64) {
    /* This `byte` is a FS, GS, Operand-size or address-size override prefix */
}
if ((byte & 0xFC) == 0xF0) {
    if (byte != 0xF1) {
        /* This `byte` is a LOCK, REPN(E/Z) or REP(_/E/Z) prefix */
    }
}
```

Coming from Intel, I would except that this last group would be possible to check in only one operation.

Then, the final question is: Can I check in one operation if the byte is 0xF0, 0xF2 or 0xF3?

Comment: You might try asking this on code golf. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183492/intel-prefixes-instructions-checking-optimisations-problems, considered as off-topic

Comment: In order for it to be on-topic there, it would need to be reworded as a puzzle.

Comment: @prl There's pretty much no way of rewriting this question into something that fits on PPCG without it completely losing its current meaning/request. PPCG is for competitions 99% of the time, and writing an on-topic non-challenge is really hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then, the final question is: Can I check in one operation if the byte is 0xF0, 0xF2 or 0xF3?

The closest you can get to one instruction is something like:

```
                     ;ecx = the byte
    bt [table],ecx   ;Is the byte F0, F2 or F3?
    jc .isF0F2orF3   ; yes
```

However, sometimes a prefix isn't considered a prefix (e.g. `pause` instruction, which is encoded like `rep nop` for compatibility with old CPUs).

Also note that for a high speed disassembler the fastest approach is likely "jump table driven", where one register points to the table corresponding to the decoder's state and another register contains the next byte of the instruction, like:

```
                          ;ebx = address of table corresponding to the decoder's current state
    movzx eax,byte [esi]  ;eax = next byte of the instruction
    inc esi               ;esi = address of byte after the next byte of this instruction
    jmp [ebx+eax*4]       ;Go to the code that figures out what to do
```

In this case, some of the pieces of code jumped to would set some flags without changing the current table (e.g. the entry for 0xF3 in the initial table would cause a jump to code that sets a "rep prefix was seen" flag), and some of the pieces of code jumped to would switch to a different table (e.g. the entry for 0x0F in the initial table would cause a jump to code that changes `EBX` to point to a completely different table used for all instructions that begin with an `0x0F, ...`); and some of the pieces of code jumped to would display an instruction (and reset the state of the decoder).

For example; for `pause` the code might be:

```
table0entryF3:
    or dword [prefixes],REP
    movzx eax,byte [esi]                ;eax = next byte of the instruction
    inc esi                             ;esi = address of byte after the next byte
    jmp [ebx+eax*4]

table0entry90:
    mov edx,instructionNameString_NOP
    test dword [prefixes],REP           ;Was it a PAUSE or NOP?
    je doneInstruction_noOperands       ; NOP, current name is right
    and dword [prefixes],~REP           ; PAUSE, pretend the REP prefix wasn't there
    mov edx,instructionNameString_PAUSE ;        and use the right name
    jmp doneInstruction_noOperands

doneInstruction_noOperands:
    call displayPrefixes
    call displayInstructionName
    mov dword [prefixes],0              ;Reset prefixes
    mov ebx,table0                      ;Switch current table back to the initial table
    movzx eax,byte [esi]                ;eax = first byte of next instruction
    inc esi                             ;esi = address of byte after the next byte
    jmp [ebx+eax*4]
```

Comment: The OP didn't said "1 operation", not "1 instruction", and `bt [mem], reg` is quite slow (10 uops on Skylake, worse than manually emulating it with shift/mask to break down the bit-index into byte offset + mask.)  Checking for just those 3 bytes is maybe best done with a range-check and then a `bt` into an *immediate* bitmap.  Like `sub eax, 0xf0` / `jnc not_fx_prefix` / `bt ecx, eax` / `jnc not_fx_prefix` where `ecx` holds `0b1101`.  But I guess the OP's mask and reject `0xf1` is actually better.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes; Skylake is slow because an instruction that should only be "5 operations" (split index into dword number and bit number, add dword number to address, fetch dword, extract bit, set flags) uses more uops than it does on all the CPUs that use less uops.

Comment: Well to be fair, it's about that slow on all Intel since Core2.  It was slightly faster on Pentium-M and P6.  AMD Ryzen decodes it to only 5 uops, but has some artificial bottleneck that limits it to 3 cycle throughput.  On K10 it's 5 uops and one per 2 clocks, but otherwise the best throughputs are Ryzen at 3 and Bulldozer at 3.5.  So it seems most CPUs run it more slowly than necessary, unless those are just front-end effects from a microcoded instruction.